# when I compile the Android.mk, it comes error couldn't find .so.toc

Tags: android, android-ndk, android.mk

I want to use libcdrmclient_sw.so to make SHARED_LIBRARIES, and i'll use one func defined in libcdrmclient_sw.so like this

```
int CDRMC_CheckPolicy(void* sessionHandle, char *destData, unsigned int *destDataLen);
```

just another same declaration

I modify the Android.mk of hookPolicy like this

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hookPolicy.c

LOCAL_MODULE := libhookPolicy
LOCAL_MULTILIB := 32
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PROPRIETARY_MODULE := true

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := liblog libc libcdrmclient_sw

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

But I always get the following error.

```
ninja: error: ‘**out/target/product/hikey960/obj/lib/libcdrmclient_sw.so.toc’**, needed by ‘out/target/product/hikey960/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libhookPolicy_intermediates/LINKED/libhookPolicy.so’, missing and no known rule to make it
12:47:18 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

Comment: Where does this libcdrmclient_sw.so come from? How did you build it?

Comment: thank you very much, I just found that I've used it wrong. this .so is not to be built but used. And I use the wrong LOCAL param,  when I change it to LOCAL_LDLIBS, then it compiles success.